# parse string xml with JDOM

Tags: java, string, sax, jdom, parsexml

I'm trying to parse string xml with JDOM but when I print it prints me blank. Do not print any data from my xml string.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List resultado = null;
    resultado = new ArrayList<>();
    resultado = listarDatos();
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    String xml = xstream.toXML(resultado);

    String adicionar = "<?xml version = \"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\"?> \n";
    String doctype = "<!DOCTYPE list \n>";
    String xml_m = adicionar + doctype + xml.replace("<newwebservicematerias.Materia>", "<ListaMaterias>").replace("</newwebservicematerias.Materia>", "</ListaMaterias>");
    //System.out.println(xml_m);

    org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
    try {
        org.jdom.Document doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(xml_m));
        String message = doc.getRootElement().getText();
        System.out.println(message);
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
// handle JDOMException
    } catch (IOException e) {
// handle IOException
    }

}
```

and tried with xerces and with jaxp but they throw me error.

Comment: Have you tried to check what happened in the exception clauses using System.println()? I think generated xml is not well-formed...

Answer (score 0):

The `getText()` method in your code is not serving the purpose. It returns the text inside the element but since there is no text but child elements that is why the desired output is not printed. Here is the modified code:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class JdomExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<String> resultado = listarDatos();
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        String xml = xstream.toXML(resultado);
        // System.out.println("xml = " + xml);

        String adicionar = "<?xml version = \"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\"?> \n";
        String doctype = "<!DOCTYPE list \n>";
        String xml_m = adicionar + doctype + xml.replace("<newwebservicematerias.Materia>", "<ListaMaterias>")
                .replace("</newwebservicematerias.Materia>", "</ListaMaterias>");
        // System.out.println("xml_m = " + xml_m);

        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        try {
            Document doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(xml_m));
            // System.out.println("doc = " + doc);
            Element message = doc.getRootElement();
            print(message);
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            // handle JDOMException
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle IOException
        }

    }

    public static void print(Element element) {
        XMLOutputter outp = new XMLOutputter();
        String s = outp.outputString(element);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    private static List<String> listarDatos() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("hello");
        list.add("world");
        return list;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<list>
  <string>hello</string>
  <string>world</string>
</list>
```

Comment: Please, can you public (jdom2 .jar) ? I have one (JDOM 2.X) but your method with this not function.

Comment: OK, it is working. but i want to print my result,without tags. e.g : hello....string.